# How to make biblatex persistent choice in kile for Bibliography settings?

Tags: biblatex, kile

In kile, there is a setting:

`LaTeX -> Bibliography -> Settngs -> Settings for biblatex`

I would like to know the following regarding this setting:

(a) what does it do? (because there doesn't seem to be any difference between choosing bibtex and biblatex); and

(b) assuming (a) does something useful to me, to make the selection of biblatex persistent across different kile sessions. AFAIK, I need to set it afresh each time I open up kile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Switching my comment to an answer</sub>

At the moment this setting is useless. By choosing **LaTeX** -> **Bibliography** -> **book** you will get all allowed keys of `biblatex` and normal bibliography-styles. For example: `lastchecked` isn't defined by `jurabib` and `biblatex` instead both packages provide the key `urldate`.